# WHERE conditions in subquery while using ANSI joins

Tags: oracle, join, ansi-sql, ora-00900

Why doesn't it work?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM dual a
     JOIN (SELECT * FROM dual WHERE 1=1) b
     ON (1=1);
```

I get "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement".
Is there a way to use WHERE clause inside the subquery?

Edit: Version 9.2

```
SELECT *
FROM v$version
```

Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production

The following executes just fine:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM dual a
     JOIN (SELECT * FROM dual /*WHERE 1=1*/) b
     ON (1=1)
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle? I just tried this query on Oracle 10g and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me on 9.2 (32 bit version is the only difference):

```
SQL> SELECT a.*
  2  FROM dual a
  3       JOIN (SELECT * FROM dual WHERE 1=1) b
  4       ON (1=1);

D
-
X

SQL> quit
Disconnected from Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
With the OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
JServer Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
```

Comment: This is what solved my problem. Turns out it was a bug in SQL Navigator. Works fine in SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 1):

What version are you using?

The exact same SQL works fine for me (Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle below `9i` does not support `ANSI` join syntax.

Use this if you're on `8i` and below:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    dual a,
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    dual
        WHERE   1 = 1
        ) b
WHERE   1 = 1
```

Comment: I've edited the question to show that my version (9.2) supports ANSI joins but not this one particular.

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct to me and I am able to execute it in 10g, but it fails with 8i, which version of Oracle are you using?